# ClassNotFoundException even when the class is available

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My issue is even when class `OrderDAO` and `OrderDAOIml` is available I'm getting this error, even though everything was running just fine. My stacktrace is below :

```
   SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml] for bean with name 'dataDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml] for bean with name 'dataDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.exclusively.oms.service.OrderServiceIml] for bean with name 'dataServices' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exclusively.oms.service.OrderServiceIml
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)

    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1320)
    ... 49 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml] for bean with name 'dataDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1320)
    ... 51 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.exclusively.oms.service.OrderServiceIml] for bean with name 'dataServices' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exclusively.oms.service.OrderServiceIml
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.detectMappedInterceptors(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext
    ... 51 more

Oct 12, 2015 3:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet spring
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType
```

My spring-servlet.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.exclusively.oms" />  

<mvc:annotation-driven />  

<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_db" />  
<property name="username" value="root" />  
<property name="password" value="root" />  
</bean>  

<bean id="sessionFactory"  
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
<property name="annotatedClasses">  
<list>  
<value>com.exclusively.oms.entity.Order</value>  
</list>  
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">  
<props>  
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>  
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
</props>  
</property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="txManager"  
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">  
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />  
</bean>  


<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"  
class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="dataDao" class="com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml"></bean>  
<bean id="dataServices" class="com.exclusively.oms.service.OrderServiceIml"></bean>  

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

</beans>
```

And web.xml:

```xml
 <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

 <web-app>
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: May be a stupid question but is your file has the same name? `Iml` and not `Impl`?

Comment: yes its iml not impl.

Comment: Could you please refresh your project once and start it again?

Comment: Maybe the code isn't deployed correctly, or the class package is incorrect.

Comment: please check whether the spellings of your packages are correct or not..

Comment: Done. Still the same error. Could you check if my spring-servlet.xml is alright

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, check whether your Java folder is added to the build path (Properties > Java Build Path > Source)

Answer (score 1):

`ClassNotFoundException` can not be thrown if class exists under class path.  It willbe for sure code issue. These can be the reasons  :-

1) Class exists but not deployed under classpath/right folder

2) As its `ClassNotFoundException` which is thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name, so compilation can pass but it will be a issue at run time. So may be look up package is not correct but deployed at right path

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this from commandline using the same classpath:

```
javap com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml
javap com.exclusively.oms.service.OrderServiceIml
```

If those classes exist, a description of their APIs would apper. In case not, an error.